# Is it possible to send data while receiving audio with a bluetooth module

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth

BM64 bluetooth module supports the following profiles :
A2DP 1.3, AVRCP 1.6, HFP 1.6, HSP 1.2 and SPP 1.2

Using the A2DP I can stream audio output to a speaker as it is for a sink, thus a speaker.

I want to send some information from the uC to the bluetooth module and thus to whatever device is paired with the module probably using SPP.

However, is that possible while still transmitting audio from the paired device to the module?

i get that they are different profiles, but my question if it is possible to send my data over A2DP instead of SPP. even if it was not audio, while handling the software side properly.

Comment: Have you read the data sheets? Is this question really relevant to an EE site?

Comment: hmm yeah i did, well, i figured electronics. maybe someone with bluetooth module experience, which site do you think its relevant to ?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth protocol is full duplex.
But as far as I can see the A2DP doesn't support this.

> ....from the A2DP profile to the Handsfree Profile in order to run full
>   duplex audio (this is not possible in A2DP)...
>
> A2PD is designed to uni-directionally transfer an audio stream in up to 2
>   channel stereo, either to or from the Bluetooth host.